# Jadx Assert.notNull view full parameters

Tags: java, android, decompiling

I noticed that in many methods of many android applications, Jadx decompile some code (probably something containing callbacks) in the following way

```java
...
final i iVar = new i();
Observable g2 = doOnSubscribe.switchMap(new Function() { // from class: ...
    @Override // io.reactivex.functions.Function
    public final Object apply(Object obj) {
        ObservableSource B;
        B = g0.B(Function1.this, obj);
        return B;
    }
}).replay(1).g();
Assert.notNull(g2, "stateSubject\n       …ay(1)\n        .refCount()");
...
```

It seems to me that the second paramenter to `Assert.notNull` is the original code of the decompiled code above it.
Is there any way to read the complete string?

Comment: The second argument of the `Assert.notNull` method is just a string that is displayed if the `g2: Observable` is `null`. It is meaningless.

Comment: Thanks, I saw it from the docs but, in many cases, it sums up perfectly some code above. Maybe it will be useless, but i'd like to read the full string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at other decompilers I noticed that the strings are exactly the same, suspension dots included. I'm still not sure, but now I'm pretty certain that it's Kotlin compiler that does this. Probably the uncut strings are not in the artifact.